# How to adjust graphics to different screens resolution and rotation?

Tags: android

I making a checkers game and the code for the xml file is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gamebackground" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board_1_" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="213dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opponent"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart ="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/withdraw"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:minHeight="10dp"
            android:minWidth="70dp"
            android:text="@string/Withdraw"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/callfortie"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:minHeight="10dp"
            android:minWidth="70dp"
            android:text="@string/Callfortie"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I 'm adding 8 rows each row contains 8 button programmatically and setting these buttons to hold the checkers image ... the problem is I tested this on Nexus one emulator and looked like this

http://i59.tinypic.com/zwb6dj.jpg

but on different resolutions it looks like this

http://i61.tinypic.com/iwucls.jpg

So any help ? :)

Comment: You need to support a multiple support screen to your application.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you do not create xml file for multiple screen support.
You should follow multi screen support as per android developer's documents. Please follow below link for more info.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html